# How to add checkboxlist selected items to string array?

Tags: c#, asp.net

```
    public string[] selected()
    {

        string[] selecteditems = new string[chbindustry.Items.Count];
        for (int i = 0; i < chbindustry.Items.Count-1; i++)
        {
            if (chbindustry.Items[i].Selected)
            {

                selecteditems[i] = chbindustry.Items[i].Text.ToString();


                //string Va = string.Empty;
                //Va = chbindustry.Items[i].Text.ToString();
               // selecteditems[i] = Va;
            }

        }
        return selecteditems;
    }
```

In this code I want to add checkboxlist selected items to string array "selecteditems[i]" here using "selecteditems[i]" I need to bind in this code and show to only selected items

```
foreach (string s in subdirectoryEntries)
            {
                DirectoryInfo d = new DirectoryInfo(s);
                for (int i = 1; i <= d.GetFiles().Length / 3; i++)
                {
                    selected();
                    Page.ClientScript.RegisterArrayDeclaration("ImgPaths", "'" + "BusinessCards/" + s.Remove(0, s.LastIndexOf('\\') + 1) + "/" + i + ".jpg'");
                    Page.ClientScript.RegisterArrayDeclaration("refs", "'" + "DesignBCs.aspx?img=BusinessCards/" + s.Remove(0, s.LastIndexOf('\\') + 1) + "/" + i + "&Side=2'");
                }
            }
```

Comment: I don't really understand the part with directories thing. Could you explain a bit more on what are you trying to achieve and how's that related to your question?

Comment: in my project one folder is there in that conains many folders like a,b,c,d and if i select a,b it should be show it in array only selected

Answer (score 4):

Did you mean this?

```
var selecteditems = chbindustry.Items.Cast<ListItem>().Where(i=>i.Selected).Select(i=>i.ToString()).ToArray();
```

Comment: i want it to add only selecterd items in array

Comment: its showing error Error 84 'System.Web.UI.WebControls.ListItemCollection' does not contain a definition for 'Where' and no extension method 'Where' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Web.UI.WebControls.ListItemCollection' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) G:\DPOasPrinted\NewDPOcopy\NewDPOcopy\BCGallery.aspx.cs 88 41 NewDPOcopy

Comment: I did not know that `Items`is an object of `ListItemCollection` type. I've updated my answer, please check it again and let me know.